# How do I match a pattern of objects in a Python iterator?

Tags: python, regex

It is very easy to use the Python re functions to match and manipulate patterns in text, for example:

```
re.match('a[efg]*c', 'aggggc')
```

How do I do the same thing on a list or other python iterator? For example, I may have a list that looks like this:

```
>>> list = ['foo', 'bar', 3, (1, 2, 3), 'a', 'b', {5, 6, 7}, 'apple']
```

And, following the regex idiom, I may want to match a pattern like so:

```
>>> pattern = ['a', '[', {7, 6, 5}, 'b', 'c', ']', '*', 'apple']
```

and I want to find a match inside this list. If it were regex, I'd write it like this:

```
>>> match = re.search(pattern, list)
>>> match.group(0)
['a', 'b', {5, 6, 7}, 'apple']
```

But, of course, it doesn't work because Python regex expects to see a string.

How do I do this?

**Note:** it's the ability to match patterns that I'm looking for, not this exact syntax. I guess, the ideal answer would be a module or library (or succinct function) that provided a variety of regex style pattern matching tools that worked on lists.

**Explanation for why I want this:** I'm working on scripts to process text from SE-Asian languages which use complex scripts. The program I'm working on now will intelligently correct typing mistakes (this language has characters which can go above, below, in front, around, etc., and have specific rules about which order they can occur in). The fist pass of my program uses a state machine to assign each character to a class, such as consonants, vowel, tone, number, etc. The second pass will try to correct invalid syllables and other kinds of mistakes. There's no analogy in English as far as the syllable bit goes, but in the numbers, suppose I saw the pattern `['number', 'o', 'number']`, then I would presume that the typist meant 'zero' rather than 'oh' and make the proper corrections.

Comment: i think `['foo', 'bar', 3, (1, 2, 3), 'a', 'b', set(5, 6, 7), 'apple']` not a valid list.

Comment: It's going to be really tricky to do if you have nested iterators (mostly because strings are iterable). Is that a requirement?

Comment: Also note that [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) is not what you're describing -- it doesn't exist in Python.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, @AvinashRaj.. it was a mistake with my set syntax.

Comment: I added the tuple and set just because I think there should be a way to match patterns of those types, but in my real project, I only need to match strings (my list might look like ['foo', 'bar', 'apple'])

Comment: @PatrickCollins, from that Wikipedia article: "pattern matching is the act of checking a given sequence of tokens for the presence of the constituents of some pattern." That's exactly what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @BenSharon Pattern matching is a feature of functional programming languages like Haskell and Standard ML, it's different from string processing with regular expressions.

Comment: @BenSharon From the wiki text on the pattern-matching tag: "Do not use this tag for regular expression questions, use [tag:regex] instead."

Comment: If I call "tokens" your items, this makes me think to some kind of [language parsing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and check if the item is a `str` before trying to match it.

```
import re
from collections import Iterable

pattern = re.compile('a[efg]*')
items = ['foo', 'bar', 3, (1, 2, 3), 'a', 'b', {5, 6, 7}, 'apple']

def _find_matches(it, pattern):
    matches = []
    for i in it:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            m = pattern.match(i)
            if m:
                matches.append(m)
        elif isinstance(i, Iterable):
            m = _find_matches(i, pattern)
            matches.extend(m)
        else:
            print "Could not process: {}".format(i)
    return matches

results = _find_matches(items, pattern)
```

Comment: This is finding all strings inside a list and sub lists that match a pattern. I'm looking for a way to match a pattern of **the elements** in the list... not the same. If it was possible, I'd like to write `re.match(['apple', '*', 'banana'], ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana'])`

Comment: ok, I see.  As Patrick was mentioning in the comments, regular expressions are used to match patterns in strings, not patterns of objects.  I'm not familiar with the application of this use case.  You may want to clarify why you want to do this, or maybe even re-consider doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you would need to write a function for checking this. some thing like this.

```
import sys


my_list =  ['foo', 'bar', 3, (1, 2, 3), 'a', 'b', {5, 6, 7}, 'apple']
pattern = ['fo', 'bar', 3, (1, 2, 3), 'a', '*', {5, 6, 7}, 'apple']


if len(my_list) != len(pattern):
    print('List length dose not match with the pattern')
    sys.exit(1)

for offset,value in enumerate(my_list):
    if pattern[offset] != value and pattern[offset] != '*':
        print('Pattern matching failed at offset {} with value {}'.format(offset, my_list[offset]))
        break;
else:
    print('Pattern matched perfectly..');
```

Comment: OK, this is a start. But the '*' term means "match zero or more occurrences of the previous item." And, what if I want the equivalent of the regex `[abcd]` (match any of a set)? I guess what I'm looking for is a module or library that is the regex equivalent for lists and tuples.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such module as part of standard python library. You can create a library for this and publish it. In what kind of scenario you are using this ? because i dont see any practical application of matching a regex pattern over an list which contains heterogeneous objects.